# display list of array from json object in a table rows by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

In my code below I have JSON data and I want to display output from it in table rows but am ending to not understand how to display it

the result I am getting looks like this:

[image]

All rows from the array are in one row instead of five rows as the number of data

I am failing to understand how to get data from this JSON and using it  what is the best approach on this and how to display it on my browser

```js
var jsonData = `{
  "rows": [
    [
      "EzE8xZ31zfC",
      "R7TPl8q81Ft",
      "47.0"
    ],
    [
      "hTUspcBc4Yn",
      "R7TPl8q81Ft",
      "50.6"
    ],
    [
      "EzE8xZ31zfC",
      "xGojHNSrFAj",
      "40.0"
    ],
    [
      "E31SemmmFGb",
      "xGojHNSrFAj",
      "74.8"
    ],
    [
      "hTUspcBc4Yn",
      "xGojHNSrFAj",
      "77.0"
    ],
    [
      "E31SemmmFGb",
      "R7TPl8q81Ft",
      "47.0"
    ]
  ]
}`;

//Converting JSON to JS Object
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

const rows = obj["rows"];

let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  text += rows[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <table style="width:100%" class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Dimension</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="demo"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>

    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: @SimoneRossaini [there is no such thing as a json "object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;` puts all the data into one cell. I don't think you want this?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini JSON is always a string. That is not the issue here.

Comment: `instead of five rows as the number of data` You have 6 rows of data...

Answer (score 1):

I think you were missing the issue that `rows` property was an array of arrays. You can create elements of the table when you iterate the list.

You need to **myTable** id to find the table. And then create each row/cell.

The solution allows for you to add more records to the JSON without adding further code.

```js
    function fillTable() {
        var jsonData = ` {
               
                "rows": [
                    [
                        "EzE8xZ31zfC",
                        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
                        "47.0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "hTUspcBc4Yn",
                        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
                        "50.6"
                    ],
                    [
                        "EzE8xZ31zfC",
                        "xGojHNSrFAj",
                        "40.0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "E31SemmmFGb",
                        "xGojHNSrFAj",
                        "74.8"
                    ],
                    [
                        "hTUspcBc4Yn",
                        "xGojHNSrFAj",
                        "77.0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "E31SemmmFGb",
                        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
                        "47.0"
                    ]
                ]
            }`;
        //Converting JSON Object to JS Object
        
        let obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        const rows = obj["rows"];
        let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        rows.map((elem, index) => {
            let row = table.insertRow(index + 1); 
            elem.map((elem, index) => {
               let cell = row.insertCell(index);
               cell.innerHTML = elem;
            });
        });


    }

    fillTable();
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="myTable" style="width:100%" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Place</th>
                <th>Dimension</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added all the data into the one cell with id demo.

Instead add thead and tbody and use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var jsonData = `{ "rows": [ [ "EzE8xZ31zfC", "R7TPl8q81Ft", "47.0" ], [ "hTUspcBc4Yn", "R7TPl8q81Ft", "50.6" ], [ "EzE8xZ31zfC", "xGojHNSrFAj", "40.0" ], [ "E31SemmmFGb", "xGojHNSrFAj", "74.8" ], [ "hTUspcBc4Yn", "xGojHNSrFAj", "77.0" ], [ "E31SemmmFGb", "R7TPl8q81Ft", "47.0" ] ] }`;

//Converting JSON string to JS Object
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj["rows"]
  .map(row => `<tr><td>${row[0]}</td><td>${row[1]}</td><td>${row[2]}</td>`).join("")
```

```html
<div>
  <table style="width:100%" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Dimension</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an html error, after close `<thead>` you open a `<tr>`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Leftover from OP's code. Removed

Answer (score 0):

You can create the whole table from scratch, something like:

```js
const rows = JSON.parse(getJSONData()).rows;
const headerLine = `<tr><th>${`Place,Dimension,Value`.split(",").join("</th><th>")}</tr>`;
const getRow = (acc, row) => `${acc}<tr>${row.map(r => `<td>${r}</td>`).join(``)}</tr>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`,
  `<table>
    <thead>${headerLine}</thead>
    <tbody>${rows.reduce(getRow, ``)}</tbody>
  </table>`);
  
//-----------------------
function getJSONData() {
  return `{
    "rows": [
      [
        "EzE8xZ31zfC",
        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
        "47.0"
      ],
      [
        "hTUspcBc4Yn",
        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
        "50.6"
      ],
      [
        "EzE8xZ31zfC",
        "xGojHNSrFAj",
        "40.0"
      ],
      [
        "E31SemmmFGb",
        "xGojHNSrFAj",
        "74.8"
      ],
      [
        "hTUspcBc4Yn",
        "xGojHNSrFAj",
        "77.0"
      ],
      [
        "E31SemmmFGb",
        "R7TPl8q81Ft",
        "47.0"
      ]
    ]
  }`;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 3px double #999;
}

td, th {
  padding: 2px 3px;
}

td:not(:last-child),
th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```